# .data segment seems to contain code?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

I have recently been trying to improve my skills on reverse engineering. So, I opened `C:/Windows/System32/DriverStore/FileRepository/xboxgip.inf_amd64_90ed6b3fdc759a5b/devauthe.sys` in IDA. While playing around the file, I came across the following bytes under `.data` segment:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 32 A2 DF 2D
99 2B 00 00 CD 5D 20 D2  66 D4 FF FF 01 00 D2 8B
0A 35 60 BD F1 C9 D6 5D  6C 59 51 D5 24 FD 02 F5
43 26 29 79 53 3E B0 FB  2B 97 BF 5E FC 20 02 00
54 B4 F2 54 77 D2 99 71  BD 9C 0B 85 C9 D0 29 BE
85 AD 6B CB D7 CA 71 D4  AB 28 DB FA 1A 0E E0 9F
03 00 B0 EB 26 B7 F4 68  74 C7 34 F0 18 10 26 20
01 BB 63 6E F6 20 E2 3B  D7 7B D1 1A B4 6D 33 BA
6B 4B 5C D0 0D 95 6B 2F  CF 0D 53 C5 AE AC 03 87
23 9B A4 BE 5D 70 E1 26  19 06 56 49 79 E6 7C 1A
71 20 D0 11 C1 D8 7C 61  44 3A 47 B2 9E 8E 44 AB
2E 42 EB 59 B0 3B F1 9C  B1 66 4F A3 DA 37 1F 30
5B 7E FF E5 FC 87 00 00  00 00 00 00 C9 57 84 41
69 9B 06 7E C1 14 C5 CA  C1 56 B7 8F 71 48 4A FC
08 1D A5 E6 C9 DB F6 53  A6 15 78 5F F4 46 C1 48
76 3B DF 9B 84 5B A3 49  5C 46 B5 D1 66 81 8A 53
E5 EC 02 85 02 2C 4B 24  61 9E 3C 2A A5 28 4D 85
F7 A6 25 45 B4 4D EC FD  A0 CD AB 01 8D B3 71 07
DA 93 06 6E D6 37 A1 16  EF 74 E1 A6 BC E0 CE E7
D4 02 C9 C1 40 5B CD 3B  9A 62 84 39 E8 40 3D 13
20 E2 1A B6 3C D3 E6 7A  C6 F3 27 B4 6D 66 5B 8D
52 81 06 0F 3C BC F3 1C  05 90 77 67 8B 99 FD 00
04 AD 27 E9 1D B5 68 B2  21 A6 0D A5 81 C0 53 C9
99 B4 ED F1 11 D0 01 91  59 A8 ED 80 BA 82 86 62
CF 3D 94 70 C3 1C 50 9E  C6 95 6D 57 17 0F 95 DA
14 38 76 38 09 E7 D5 0C  3E 89 2F 5D DF F4 D6 31
C1 26 02 9C 30 0B EE 28  A7 86 74 A3 46 8F B7 85
FA 8C 0F BB 79 65 A5 AD  C9 12 BA CF 43 64 CC 62
A0 30 3F AE 88 06 40 86  EF 27 CA 93 52 53 41 32
```

Looking at the bytes, it doesn't seem to be ASCII strings, neither does it look to be code, since disassemblers fails on certain bytes. I understand my question might be a bit vague, but can anyone tell me what this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `.data` segment are generally — as it name suggest — simply *data*.

Data are *not only ASCII strings*, but other data, too. For example, integers and floating-point numbers. They are encoded as sequences of bits, and are preferably displayed — as in your question — in the form of hexadecimal symbols.

Knowing nothing about their meaning, we may conclude nothing about values which they represent. Even nothing about the start and end position of individual piece of data.

For example, let's take the left half of your 3<sup>rd</sup> row: `0A 35 60 BD F1 C9 D6 5D`. What is its meaning:

- 8 bytes?
- 4 words?
- 2 double-words?
- 4 bytes and 1 double-word?
- etc., etc., ...

Even if we know that they are 2 double-words, what they represent? Integers or floating-point numbers? If integers, signed or unsigned ones? And so on.

It means that in the `.data` segment may be *everything*. **Nothing is suspicious,** if you have no other information.

Comment: would you know how to tell if they are either Integers or floating-points? I was assuming that they need to be null-terminated, but with your example on left 3rd row, there is no null byte before or afterward. of does integers and floating-points don't need to be null-terminated?

Comment: No null-termination is required for integers or floating-point numbers. (BTW, it doesn't matter in the context of your question.)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)